# wrong xinput ABI version when compiling driver from source

Tags: drivers, xorg, compiling, wacom, xinput

I am using the Lenovo X1 Yoga tablet, and I need a custom version of the xf86-input-wacom driver to make my pen work as desired. In this process, I discovered that some header files contain version information that is not consistent with the actual installation. My question is how to obtain the correct development files to allow me to compile this driver from source.

What I did:

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS on my Lenovo X1 Yoga Tablet. The pen works, but produces some spurious input data. To fix this, I need to install a custom version of the xf86-input-wacom driver: See the discussion at https://sourceforge.net/p/linuxwacom/bugs/339/. Following the instructions in the second comment on that page, I did the following.

```
$ sudo apt-get install autoconf pkg-config make xutils-dev libtool xserver-xorg-dev libx11-dev libxi-dev libxrandr-dev libxinerama-dev libudev-dev
```

to install the development files (some of the packages were already installed.)

```
$ git clone https://github.com/jigpu/xf86-input-wacom -b fix-bug-339
```

to get the specific branch I need.

```
$ cd xf86-input-wacom
$ ./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr && make
```

to compile the driver.

Since I was having problems, I manually copied the resulting driver

```
$ cp src/.libs/wacom_drv.so /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/wacom_drv.so
```

Upon reboot, no wacom devices are visible to xinput. The problem is found in

```
/var/log/Xorg.0.log:

[    11.725] (II) LoadModule: "wacom"
[    11.725] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/wacom_drv.so
[    11.726] (II) Module wacom: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    11.726]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 0.35.0
[    11.726]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    11.726]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 22.1
[    11.726] (EE) wacom: module ABI major version (22) doesn't match the server's version (24)
[    11.726] (II) UnloadModule: "wacom"
[    11.726] (II) Unloading wacom
```

So why would the xinput ABI version of a module that was just compiled from source be behind the version of the X server? Let's take a look at

```
/usr/include/xorg/xf86Module.h:

#define ABI_ANSIC_VERSION       SET_ABI_VERSION(0, 4)
#define ABI_VIDEODRV_VERSION    SET_ABI_VERSION(20, 0)
#define ABI_XINPUT_VERSION      SET_ABI_VERSION(22, 1)
#define ABI_EXTENSION_VERSION   SET_ABI_VERSION(9, 0)
#define ABI_FONT_VERSION        SET_ABI_VERSION(0, 6)
```

So indeed, the version is 22 according to this header file, but the actual version from my fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS is 24.

So my question is, how do I get the correct development files that will allow me to compile a driver compatible with the version of Xorg that comes with Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS?

Incidentally, I was able to get this working by having my friend compile the driver on his Fedora system that has compatible versions. I just copied his wacom_drv.so to /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input. But in the future I would like to be able to maintain this without his help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more searching and I have resolved the problem. As far as I can tell, the default version of Xorg that comes with Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS corresponds to the packages with the suffix

```
*-hwe-16.04
```

When I installed the development files, I installed the package

```
xserver-xorg-dev
```

This was not correct. I should have installed

```
xserver-xorg-dev-hwe-16.04
```

Though I'm not sure how I as a user was supposed to know that. Anyway, installing that package, recompiling, and reinstalling resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely I had exact same problem with mtrack today. I fixed it by doing clean checkout (git clone to be precise) and re-running autoreconf and ./configure.
But I still can't figure out how to clean original directory.